# Is the phrase " Macron fact-checks Trump mid-conversation for false claim on Isis fighters" missing an apostrophe?

Tags: grammar

The "mid-conversation" part is Trump's mid- conversation right?

Answer (score 3):

No, it should not be "Trump's mid-conversation".
A conversation does not belong to any of its participants.

["Mid-conversation"](https://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=mid-&title=21st) is a compound adverbial phrase and means "in the middle of the conversation". Macron and Trump were talking, and Macron interrupted Trump to check a fact.

Comment: Mid-conversation I guess is a compound word which looks like a noun, a compound noun to be precise, that's why I thought an apostrophe was missing.

Comment: Now am confused. Is it a compound word or a sort of abbreviation?

Comment: I agree with this except that it is possible to modify "conversation" with a possessive. E.g.: "I'm referring to our conversation yesterday." "The book describes the prime minister's conversations with other world leaders."

Comment: @MarcInManhattan good point.